# Using a string to refer to a structure array - matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to take the averages of a pretty large set of data, so i have created a function to do exactly that. 
The data is stored in some `struct1.struct2.data(:,column)`
there are 4 `struct1` and each of these have between 20 and 30 sub-`struct2` 
the data that I want to average is always stored in column 7 and I want to output the average of each `struct2.data(:,column)` into a `2xN` array/double (column 1 of this output is a reference to each sub-`struct2` column 2 is the average)

The omly problem is, I can't find a way (lots and lots of reading) to point at each structure properly. I am using a string to refer to the structures, but I get error `Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.` So clearly it doesn't like this. Here is what I used. (excuse the inelegence)

```
function [avrg] = Takemean(prefix,numslits)
% place holder arrays
avs = [];
slits = [];
% iterate over the sub-struct (struct2)
for currslit=1:numslits
    dataname = sprintf('%s_slit_%02d',prefix,currslit);
    % slap the average and slit ID on the end
    avs(end+1) = mean(prefix.dataname.data(:,7));
    slits(end+1) = currslit;
end
% transpose the arrays
avs = avs';
slits = slits';
avrg = cat(2,slits,avs); % slap them together
```

It falls over at this line `avs(end+1) = mean(prefix.dataname.data,7);` because as you can see, `prefix` and `dataname` are strings. So, after hunting around I tried making these strings variables with `genvarname()` still no luck!

I have spent hours on what should have been 5min of coding. :'(

Edit: Oh `prefix` is a string e.g. `'Hs'` and the structure of the structures (lol) is e.g. `Hs.Hs_slit_XX.data()` where `XX` is e.g. `01,02,...27`

Edit: If I just run `mean(Hs.Hs_slit_01.data(:,7))` it works fine... but then I cant iterate over all of the `_slit_XX`

Comment: When you say "there are 4 `struct1` and each of these have between 20 and 30 sub-`struct2`", are you talking about arrays of structures, or separate fields with different names?

Comment: I am not sure. Basically going by the added example `Hs` is a 1x1 struct but contains `Hs_slit_XX` - each `Hs_slit_XX` contains a 23x8 double called data and 23x6 cell called text data

Comment: Why would you pass the name of the structure instead of the structure itself in the first place?

Comment: Because I need to be able to iterate over all of the like-named substructures...

Comment: Do you want simply want to iterate over all fields with the name pattern `XX_slit_YY`?

Comment: Yeah. So it needs to be `XX.XX_slit_YY.data(:,7)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to iterate over the fields with the name pattern `<something>_slit_<something>`, you need neither the `prefix` string nor `numslits` for this. Pass the actual structure to your function, extract the desired fields and then itereate them:

```
function avrg = Takemean(s)

    %// Extract only the "_slit_" fields
    names = fieldnames(s);
    names = names(~cellfun('isempty', strfind(names, '_slit_')));

    %// Iterate over fields and calculate means
    avrg = zeros(numel(names), 2);
    for k = 1:numel(names)
        avrg(k, :) = [k, mean(s.(names{k}).data(:, 7))];
    end
```

This method uses [*dynamic field referencing*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) to access fields in structs using strings.

Comment: Didn't check performance, but a simpler way to make sure the names contain `_slit_` would be `names = names(strmatch('_slit_',names))`. --- If you only want to use existing names (and I think this is the case) than this method is definately preferred over the string construction.

Comment: This looks promising (and quicker) I will give it a shot and update you.

Comment: YES!!!! You sir, are a legend!  - and yes it is ~ 30% quicker ( took about 1sec rather than ~3sec) - Thank you!!! Have a cyber beer on me

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin actually I've replaced `regexp` with `strfind`, but I forgot to update the answer. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I would go one further.  Instead of storing your data across a bunch of sequential field names, use a cell array as a field.  So, for example, `hs.slit{1}`. And `avrg(k,:) = [k, mean(s.slit{k}.data(:,7)];`

Comment: @Peter that's a good suggestion, but it's only plausible if you are indeed willing to modify the code generating this data. This is not always guaranteed to be easy, especially in a messy code.

Comment: Of course, it's not a criticism of your answer, just food for thought for the OP.  I like to proselytize container usage whenever possible.

Comment: @Peter Yep, generalization at minimum cost is always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, think twice before you use string construction to access variables.

If you really really need it, here is how it can be used:

```
a.b=123;
s1 = 'a';
s2 = 'b';
eval([s1 '.' s2])
```

In your case probably something like:

```
Hs.Hs_slit_01.data= rand(3,7);
avs = [];

dataname = 'Hs_slit_01';
prefix = 'Hs';

eval(['avs(end+1) = mean(' prefix '.' dataname '.data(:,7))'])
```

Comment: I know no other way to iterate over the names in matlab :( cool I will try that

Comment: It may work, but for large arrays that would be tremendously slow.

Comment: I tried `avs(end+1) = mean(eval([prefix '.' dataname '.data(:,7)']));` but it gave an error `Undefined variable "Hs" or class "Hs.Hs_slit_01.data".`

Comment: @FriskyGrub That is not very strange, in your example the only inputs you give to the function are `prefix` and `numslits`. You can find this kind of stuff by using `dbstop if error`.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I tried `eval('avs(end+1) = mean(' prefix '.' dataname '.data(:,7))')` but I just get `Unexpected MATLAB expression` haha

Comment: @FriskyGrub I forgot the brackets, see my updated answer with a working example.